# Does defining Dirac delta via $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x-x_0)\ dx = f(x_0)$ make sense?

Tags: definition, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I know Dirac delta can be defined rigorously with distributions, but is the following definition absurd?

> [image: Definition]

I think so since the integral should always be 0 in the sense of Lebesgue (it takes only one positive value, but on a singleton).

Comment: The Dirac delta is not a function in the usual sense. It is what's called a distribution.

Comment: This is not a formal definition but rather some intuitive explanation.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1413826/960197

Comment: The definition is absurd, yes, although it might provide some intuition or some motivation for the rigorous definition.

Comment: Please consider writing up the excerpt in your question, not pasting a screenshot of text, as using a screenshot  that makes the key part of your question unsearchable and impossible for text-to-voice devices (used by the visually impaired) to understand.

Comment: Simply put, it **is not** and **cannot be** the Lebesgue integral. Also see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4063833/21820) for a completely elementary yet rigorous approach to the Dirac δ that suffices for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the way it is written, it is absurd. But it can be understood in the following way. If you define the *Dirac measure* $\delta$ as
$$
\delta(E)=\begin{cases}1,&\ x_0\in E\\[0.3cm] 0,&\ x_0\not\in E\end{cases}
$$
then it is easy to check that the Lebesgue integral for any $f$ is
$$\tag1
\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\,\delta(x)=f(x_0).
$$
The notation that physicists use comes from the Radon-Nikodym Theorem: if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, then there exists a function $g$ such that
$$\tag2
\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\,d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx.
$$
Of course the Dirac measure is *not* absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure. But physicists only use the Dirac delta in the equality $(1)$, never as a standalone function, so they don't run into contradictions.

Comment: I would say (from my perspective as a physicist) that physicists *often* run into contradictions with the Dirac delta, usually when they're not being sufficiently careful with their integrals.  :-)

Comment: +1. Comments: a usual notation is $\delta_{x_0}$ for the shifted Dirac delta measure you define ;) As I explained in my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3801916/working-with-infinitesimals-of-the-form-dfx-for-example-dax-and-relating/3807217#3807217, a better notation for integrals with another measure is $\int f(x)\,\mu(\mathrm d x)$. With these notations, one could write indeed
$$
\int f(x) \,\delta_{x_0}(\mathrm d x) = f(x_0)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Within the theory of integration the definition doesn't make sense. You can even call it *absurd*.

But it common, especially among physicists, to abuse or extend the integral notation (call it whatever you want) to cover the application of a distribution on a test function (which is a kind of generalization of an integral), and as such it makes sense.